# Installing rails fails - permission denied

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rvm

I am trying to set up a ruby on rails project in a Ubuntu vagrant, and I'm encountering the following problem:

Running:

```
gem install rails
```

Gives me

```
Fetching: rack-1.6.4.gem (100%)
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Errno::EACCES)
Permission denied @ rb_sysopen - /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/cache/rack-1.6.4.gem
```

Ok so it's a permissions issue. 
As suggested on some other similar topics I ran

```
sudo chmod -R 1777 tmp/
```

But this doesn't seem to help me, I'm just getting the same message again.
I know this question has been asked before, but the fixes don't work for me.

Comment: `sudo gem install rails`?

Comment: That's a different story. Vagrant and root users point to different ruby versions.
Vagrant has 2.3.0
Root has 1.9.3, which is unsupported. And I didn't manage to make root have 2.3.0. This would also fix my problem.

Comment: I know you can change it with rvm use, but I don't know why, on root, whereis rvm gives me /usr/local/rvm, but using it gives me no command rvm found

Comment: It depends if `rvm` is installed correctly for your root user. Missing `rvm.sh` in the login process will make it fail.